# Lightning RecordEdit Component - multiselect

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-duallistbox

I have custom Lightning component form but i get a javascript error on console, i suppose something i am doing wrong.

```
<!--@ggalaios 20/11/19: ea_RelationshipWithea -->
    <aura:attribute name="RelationshipWithea_Options" type="List" default="[
        { label: 'supplier', value: 'supplier' },
        { label: 'partner', value: 'partner' },
        { label: 'employee', value: 'employee' }]"/>

<lightning:dualListbox name="multipleOptions" 
                           label= "relationship" 
                           sourceLabel="available" 
                           selectedLabel="checked" 
                           options="{!v.RelationshipWithea_Options}" 
                           value="{!v.accountRecord.ea_Relationship_with_EA__c}"/>
```

and on my controller i use

```
var eaRel = component.get("v.accountRecord.ea_Relationship__c");
        var str='';
        eaRel.forEach(function(item){
            str=str+item+";";
        }, this);
        component.set("v.accountRecord.ea_Relationship__c", str);
```

The thing is that when controller is called (after a button is clicked), i see on my browser console the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.value.forEach is not a function
at M.get computedSelectedList [as computedSelectedList] (dualListbox.js:2)
at w (dualListbox.js:2)
at mo (aura_prod.js:3)
at yr (aura_prod.js:3)
at bo (aura_prod.js:3)
at aura_prod.js:3
at To (aura_prod.js:3)
at cr (aura_prod.js:3)
at Array.ir (aura_prod.js:3)
at Bt (aura_prod.js:3)
```

and after that, i cannot edit my dualListBox component... Any suggestions?

Comment: so your error occurred immediately after option click on duallist?

Comment: No, but it could. The error occured immediately after the controller section that i posted is called/executed

Comment: which event triggers controller section of code which u posted, i feel your not added all your code, please update your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grabbing your `dualListBox` element incorrectly. You need to set an `aura:id` on it and then you can use `cmp.find()`. Here is an example:

```
<aura:attribute name="RelationshipWithea_Options" type="List" default="[
        { label: 'supplier', value: 'supplier' },
        { label: 'partner', value: 'partner' },
        { label: 'employee', value: 'employee' }]"/>
<aura:attribute name="values" type="List" default="['supplier','partner']"/>

<lightning:dualListbox aura:id="selectOptions"
                       name="multipleOptions" 
                           label= "relationship" 
                           sourceLabel="available" 
                           selectedLabel="checked" 
                           options="{!v.RelationshipWithea_Options}"
                           value="{!v.values}"/>

controller:

someAction : function(cmp, evt, help) {
     var arryOfSelVals = component.find('selectOptions').get('v.value');
     var strOfVals = arryOfSelVals.join(';'); // returns 'supplier;partner'

    }

//Call this function onload of AccountRecord to set values
loadExistingValues : function(cmp,evt,help)
{
     var existStr = cmp.get('v.accountRecord.ea_Relationship_with_EA__c')
     var arryVals = existStr.split(';');
     cmp.set('v.values',arryVals)

}
```

Comment: Hi Bryan and thanks for your response. I tried this, it works fine for create new Account. But what about edit? I this case i need to load the values that the Account has and show them to the user. So i need somehow to have the value="v.accountRecord.ea_Relationship_with_EA__c"

Comment: @GiorgosGalaios are you saying load the values from your custom field so they appropriately already appear in the selected and available columns?

Comment: Yes, this is it!

Comment: @GiorgosGalaios I have updated my answer

Comment: You made my day, mate! You are amazing, thank you!!!